# How to search for the 1st occurrence of a pattern in a line using EGREP

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I am using EGREP regex to search for some patterns in a file that contains URLs. I want to find the first instance only in each line. For example, this is my regex:

```
egrep -io '^\<http(s)://home\>+\..+\.gov(\.au)?' input.txt
```

It output this instance:

```
https://home.xxx.gov/uuu.aspx?url=https://home.xxx.gov
```

But what I really look for in this specific example is:

```
https://home.xxx.gov
```

I do not care what comes after the .gov and I want to trim it. How can I do this?

Comment: Why is the `(s)` in parentheses? Should it be optional? If so, use `https?`, not `http(s)`.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker yes I want the 's' optional.

Comment: You should clarify about the desired output. Are only `.gov` and `.gov.au` domains required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a [lazy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), and for that you need Perl-style regexes:

```
egrep -P -io '^https?://home\..+?\.gov(\.au|\.uk)?' input.txt
```

If your `egrep` doesn't support Perl regexes, you need to find a different way, for example

```
egrep -io '^https?://home\.[A-Za-z0-9.]+\.gov(\.au|\.uk)?' input.txt
```

or

```
egrep -io '^https?://home\.[^/]+\.gov(\.au|\.uk)?' input.txt
```

limiting the range of characters that may be matched by the regex. See also @sshashank124's solution.

Comment: When I used -P, I got this error after typing the command in my ubuntu 12 machine: egrep: egrep can only use the egrep pattern syntax

Comment: Seems your `egrep` was compiled without Perl regex support. Does it have to be egrep, then?

Comment: the last command seems working. But, just to make sure. If I have more that possible country code say (.uk or .au or .it) then, am I correct to type it as: .gov(\.au|\.uk|\.it)

Comment: @user2192774: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that as:

`^\<https?://home\.\w+\.gov(\.au|\.uk)?`

Comment: What about the .gov I also want this. Can you please make more clarification?

Comment: Not correct. I used it. I get urls that ends with .com, .net, etc. not only .gov. Also, I got urls that starts with home such as homeland etc. but what I want is 'home.' only home followed by '.'

Comment: thnx. But how to tell the command to look for .gov.au and .gov.uk in addition to .gov only? Am I correct in my post in typing it .gov(.au). also, I do not want '/' I just want the .gov end or .gov.au

Comment: @user2192774, Updated. Please tell me if that helped.

Comment: You used '<' in the command with. Is it a mistake that u did not end it with '>' or it should be like that?

Comment: @user2192774, Mistake it is. But you shouldn't need either `<` or `>`

Comment: sshashank124 plz note that .uk .au that comes after .gov is optional. i.e. I am also looking for .gov only.

Comment: @user2192774, Yes that is what I'm doing above. It is optional